# What is ".HFS+ Private Directory Data" and why is it SO BIG?

Tags: macos, rootkit

I’m recovering this old disk I accidentally formatted, and stumbled across a hidden and HUGE folder of questionable origin.

I can plainly see the folder’s contents thru a data rescue program.  By HUGE, I mean that the size as reported by the recovery program would exceed the size of the disk from which it came - I'm assuming that this is because of Apple's use of hard links to directories, as in their Time Machine backup scheme, but I'm not certain, but based on what I've seen from how Time Machine does its magic, I'd think this could be the case.

I've looked around the Internet, and there is rumor this directory is a root kit Apple has installed on its own drives, but that is just rumor.  ;-)

Here are two pictures of the contents of this directory structure that I'm NOT planning on restoring:

[image: .HFS+ Private Directory Data Picture 1]

and

[image: .HFS+ Private Directory Data Picture 2]

So, what is this folder's purpose?

Comment: There is a complete answer here:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31734/hfs-private-directory-data .  It is essentially file system data.

Comment: Actually, after looking at the HFS+, it seems pretty obvious to me, that data is the proprietary implementation of the HFS+ concept of iNodes. I will agree with you, and I already hypothesized this, the TM implementation is contained within the HFS+ structure, but I found various types of record structures in that data, not just what would be necessary for hard linked directories.  I have more data to support this hypothesis, but not enough time to put it here. Anyone out there implement a filesystem with iNodes before?  What type of control structures are contained within?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh yeah, that would negate the idea of a "root kit" in its negative sense - it is just that Apple left part of its proprietary implementation of the HFS+ exposed for us to think about.