# APFS broke find command

Tags: macos, command-line, posix, apfs

I just upgraded to APFS on an external drive.

Now this is happening:

```
find /Volumes/FDDISK | head
/Volumes/FDDISK
/Volumes/FDDISK/.HFS+ Private Directory Data
/dir_2354142ISK/.HFS+ Private Directory Data
/dir_2354142/DatabasesPrivate Directory Data
/dir_2354142/Databases/Tagste Directory Data
/dir_2354142/Databases/Tags/61756678-6c736866-6170706c.tagset
/dir_2354142/Databases/Tags/000000c2-00000000-454d4147.tagset
/dir_2354142/Databases/Tags/61756678-67726571-6170706c.tagset
/dir_2354142/Databases/Tags/00000098-00000000-454d4147.tagset
/dir_2354142/Databases/Tags/000000c6-00000000-454d4147.tagset
```

I don't see this documented anywhere. Can anybody tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

`find` is working fine; you're seeing a HFS+ metadata directory that was previously hidden by the OS, but no longer hidden since APFS doesn't consider it special.

It has the name `.HFS+ Private Directory Data␍`, where `␍` indicates a carriage return byte (0x0D). Naturally, when printed to the terminal, it causes the cursor to move back to column #1 so the 2nd part of the path appears to be written "on top" of the 1st part.

For the purpose of this directory in HFS+ (it's no longer used in APFS), see:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31734/hfs-private-directory-data
- [What is ".HFS+ Private Directory Data" and why is it SO BIG?](https://superuser.com/questions/746361/what-is-hfs-private-directory-data-and-why-is-it-so-big)

Comment: Thank you. That is maybe the worst file name choice ever.

Comment: It's deliberate, I'm guessing. (Original Mac OS used CR as the line terminator so such a filename was impossible to enter via any program.)